# How can I call server using 8081 port

Tags: tcp

I have a server that has internal IP:

```
172.18.4.325
```

and external IP:

```
198.115.74.325
```

I can access:

```
172.18.4.325:8081/jasperserver/services/repository
```

from within server,
but how do I access it from the outside?

I added inbound and outbound rules for port `TCP 8081`, but nothing.

What am I missing?

Active TCP connections:

```
D:\lib>netstat -a

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8109           Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10990          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49158          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49163          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50231          Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         Firestorm:50240        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         Firestorm:50241        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         Firestorm:50242        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         Firestorm:50243        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         Firestorm:50244        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1433         Firestorm:50245        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1434         Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         Firestorm:50221        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         Firestorm:50237        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         Firestorm:50238        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         Firestorm:50239        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8005         Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8009         Firestorm:50432        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8009         Firestorm:50460        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8009         Firestorm:50461        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8105         Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8109         Firestorm:50252        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8109         Firestorm:50257        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8109         Firestorm:50258        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8109         Firestorm:50259        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8109         Firestorm:50260        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8109         Firestorm:50261        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50221        Firestorm:3306         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50237        Firestorm:3306         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50238        Firestorm:3306         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50239        Firestorm:3306         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50240        Firestorm:ms-sql-s     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50241        Firestorm:ms-sql-s     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50242        Firestorm:ms-sql-s     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50243        Firestorm:ms-sql-s     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50244        Firestorm:ms-sql-s     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50245        Firestorm:ms-sql-s     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50252        Firestorm:8109         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50257        Firestorm:8109         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50258        Firestorm:8109         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50259        Firestorm:8109         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50260        Firestorm:8109         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50261        Firestorm:8109         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50432        Firestorm:8009         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50460        Firestorm:8009         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50461        Firestorm:8009         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:139       Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    172.18.4.325:1433      192.168.4.78:55377     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:1433      192.168.4.78:55378     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:1433      192.168.4.78:55379     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:1433      192.168.4.78:56365     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:1433      192.168.4.78:56366     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:1433      192.168.4.78:56367     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:3389      192.168.4.78:51196     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    172.18.4.325:52756     198.135.8.228:1414     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    172.18.4.325:52760     198.135.8.228:1414     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    172.18.4.325:52767     Firestorm:50231        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    172.18.4.325:52771     198.135.8.228:1414     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    172.18.4.325:52775     198.135.8.228:1414     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    172.18.4.325:52776     172.18.5.220:1415      SYN_SENT
  TCP    [::]:135               Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:443               Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1433              Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3306              Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3389              Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5357              Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:10990             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:47001             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49152             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49153             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49154             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49155             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49158             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49163             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:50231             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:1434             Firestorm:0            LISTENING
```

Comment: What server? Apache? What OS?

Comment: Windows Server Enterprise. Apache 2.4.12 (listening on 443 secure). 64-bit OS. 8081 port is for the second instance of Tomcat

Comment: Can you ping address 198.115.74.325 from the external network?

Comment: @gomons No. It seems that I can only get to Apache 443 port.  And I don't know how to get to this link 198.115.74.325:8081/jasperserver/services/repository without going through Apache :/

Comment: Also you can check what address and port listening apache. Whether it listening only `172.18.4.325`, only `0.0.0.0` or it listening both `172.18.4.325` and `198.115.74.325`

Comment: So can you get to 198.115.74.325:443/jasperserver/services/repository ?

Comment: @gomons Yea... :)  Put that as an answer and I will accept it :) Thank you

Comment: But I can't understand how I helped you (=

Comment: I changed properties file to point to https://198.115.74.325:443/jasperserver/services/repository instead of http://198.115.74.325:8081/jasperserver/services/repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try get to your server using port `443`, that usually enabled on firewall:

```
198.115.74.325:443/jasperserver/services/repository
```

I think that firewall still blocks port `8081`.